# Node JS web application deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

I'm developing my first node js web application with Angular 6 front end.

The app works fine in the local environment, but it doesn't work in Azure web app service.

In my web app service, sample (hello world) node js app runs fine. But when I deploy my application which has Angular front end, it does not work(but pages are loading).

I think server is not running, but I don't know how to fix it. I have followed a lot of documentation, but none of them fixed my problem.

Please help. let me know if you need more info.

I'm getting this error when I request functionalities from server.

```
GET https://ntest4.azurewebsites.net/logincheck/actualusername/actualpassword 404 (Not Found)
 ERROR e {headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://ntest4.azurewebsites.net/logincheck/actualusername/actualpassword", ok: false, …}
```

Dist folder structure:

[image]

Comment: have you ever tried to `npm install` in your service to prepare the `node_modules`?

Comment: No . I just build the project and deployed dist folder to my web app service using VS code. Am i missing something?

Comment: have a try `npm install` and `nvm list` to check which `node` version you are using to ensure it's `8.x or 10.x` and then `ng serve` your frontend.

Comment: Thanks . I will do that and let you know the progress

Comment: Seems like I already installed those . My app runs fine in the localhost

Comment: I am quite sure about your question **In my web app service**? Isn't that deployed remotely?

Comment: Yes it is deployed remotely and also i tried using power shell

Comment: so you need to **re-install** and **re-configure** your working environment there as you do for your local.

Comment: Can u instruct me on that?

Comment: Are you sure the link exists? `https://ntest4.azurewebsites.net/logincheck/actualusername/actualpassword`

Answer (score 0):

You seems to use the HTML5 History mode, you may need to turn all other access to index.html on the service.

（and when I visit `https://ntest4.azurewebsites.net`, return no permission.）

Comment: How can I disable the history mode?. Can you please try this link https://ntest4.azurewebsites.net/AngularLogin

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })` look at Angular's [hashlocationstrategy](https://angular.cn/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)

Comment: Seems to be some other problem. But thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `power-shell` to log into your remote instance/service, the whole working environment will be different from your local's.

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to:

- first, make sure the `node -v` is correct, as [specific version](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#nodejs) required; if not, you have to manually install that following the [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/);
- second, you need to *re-install* all required modules under your project folder `npm install`;
- then, you should be able to start your project by `ng serve`.

Please have a check and let me know if anything goes wrong.

#### One more trick

You can check whether your server is up by

- `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 4200`
  or
- `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep 4200`

in your remote.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But there is something wrong with my app. Since I'm new to all these technologies, I think I have made a lot of mistakes. I'm still working on it. Thank you for your time and help.